# Sum 6 months worth of data per team name in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, jupyter

I'm trying to sum 6 months of data separately for each team name I have, so that I can perform a linear regression model. I've used the following code, however it is grouping everything in my dataset, rather than just 'Area Team Name', which is specified in the code.

```
 pivoted_df = pd.pivot_table(sample(), index="Month",values=["Actual Cost", "Area Team 
 Name"], aggfunc=np.sum)
 print(pivoted_df)
```

Which gives me a result of...

```
 Actual Cost
 Month                  
 AUGUST     2.156021e+07
 DECEMBER   3.282076e+07
 JULY       3.421666e+07
 NOVEMBER   3.370295e+07
 OCTOBER    3.466268e+07
 SEPTEMBER  3.371625e+07
```

Comment: Welcome to SO, please read [tour] and [mre] and in this case also: [how-to-make-good-reproducible-pandas-examples](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20109391/how-to-make-good-reproducible-pandas-examples)

Comment: Check out the documentation: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.pivot_table.html . You may need to add a column parameter with `Area Team Name`?

Answer (score 0):

Since `'Area Team Name'` is in the `values`, it is trying to include that in the sum function. I imagine they aren't numbers, so it isn't having success summing them.

If you want the team names as rows, you'll need to add it to `index` (although you may want to just do a `groupby()` at that point; if you want them as columns (so the rows would be the months as you have, and then more columns with the team names, you'll need to add the parameter `columns='Area Team Name'`.